# Update-Package –reinstall removed all packages.config in VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget

When I run `Update-Package –reinstall` on my solution in VS2013 sometimes it ends with an error and the packages.config files in all projects are gone. Why do all my packages.config files get removed?

```
PM> Update-Package –reinstall
Reinstalling 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi 5.2.2' in project 'Bidrik.WebAPI'.
Removing 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi 5.2.2' from Bidrik.WebAPI.
Successfully removed 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi 5.2.2' from Bidrik.WebAPI.
Uninstalling 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi 5.2.2'.

...

Successfully removed 'mongocsharpdriver 1.9.2' from Tiny.Render.Pdf.
Uninstalling 'mongocsharpdriver 1.9.2'.
Successfully uninstalled 'mongocsharpdriver 1.9.2'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost (≥ 5.2.2 && < 5.3.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core (≥ 5.2.2 && < 5.3.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client (≥ 5.2.2)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Newtonsoft.Json (≥ 6.0.4)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Net.Http (≥ 2.2.22)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Bcl (≥ 1.1.9)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build (≥ 1.0.14)'.
Update-Package : Already referencing a newer version of 'mongocsharpdriver'.
At line:1 char:15
+ Update-Package <<<<  –reinstall
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Update-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.UpdatePackageCommand
```